# is_callable on Mockery::mock() always returns true

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

My code branches depending on whether mocked object has method or not.

In actual class I have 2 options to check for method existence: `is_callable` and `method_exists`.

```
// Defining mocks for test
$emptyMock = m::mock();
$mockWithExpectation = m::mock()
    ->shouldReceive('foo')
    ->andReturn('bar')->getMock();

// Trying to perform checks inside of tested class
method_exists($emptyMock, 'foo'); // false
method_exists($mockWithExpectation, 'foo'); // false

is_callable([$emptyMock, 'foo']); // true
is_callable([$mockWithExpectation, 'foo']); // true
```

Let's call these methods on mock.

```
$emptyMock->foo(); // \BadMethodCallException
$mockWithExpectation->foo(); // 'bar'
```

As you can see, methods execute/fail properly.

Is it possible to figure out whether method is callable without tested class knowing explicitly that he's handling mock.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: If an object has the magic __call() method implemented, then is_callable() will return TRUE for any non-existent method, while method_exists() will return FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I went too far with mockery as the functionality I required exists in vanilla PHPunit.

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(stdClass::class)
    //->setMethods(['foo']) 
    ->getMock();

is_callable([$mock, 'foo']); // gives true only if foo is set
```